# Zabbix server sends too many notifications

Tags: zabbix

I've recently installed Zabbix server on a VPS and am very happy with it.
I've installed the client on appr. 6-7 other VPSs and everything works fine. The interface is smooth, and it produces some very nice graphs. 
My only problem with the software is that I've set it up to send notifications on problems, but im receiving between 30 and 60 emails every day. Always something along "Server XXX is unreachable: PROBLEM", and a minute later: "Server XXX is unreachable: OK".
Off course, Zabbix also recognizes when there are real problems, and e.g. when a server has been restarted. It just seems to me as if Zabbix very fast "gives up", or maybe times out faster than what suits my needs.
I've been trying to google this problem several times, but given up, so now I'm trying this approach.

Does anyone know of how to adjust the fidelity of these notifications/triggers?

Comment: are you using the default example templates ? if so, it most likely is the "status" item, which, actually is not suggested :) - you should change instead to agent.ping to check host availability

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/escalations_and_repeated_notifications/delayed_notifications
I am using escalation functionality of Zabbix to suppress frequent On/Off messages. In general:

- first messages trigger escalation chain, w/out emailing you
- then, Zabbix waits for 5 mins (or whatever you set it up to) before sending a notification.
- if in course of those 5 mins trigger state changes to off, you get NO notification and everything goes back to normal.
- Nice part it that deshboard still shows

Oleg

Comment: Thanks! That seems like what I was looking for.
I adjusted the settings, and am now giving the system some time to see how the notification sending is affected.

Comment: After waiting patiently (and relaxing some web triggers), Zabbix emailing is finally working properly now. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5):

You can adjust the triggers as well.  I've found the count() method handy.
Instead of triggering on last(0) try count(300,0,"eq")}>5 instead.   This trigger an exception if the last 5 checks (assuming 60 seconds between checks) failed.

http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/config/triggers

You can also disable the OK messages by adding the 'Trigger value = "PROBLEM"' condition.  This change should be made in the actions configuration.

http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/config/actions

Comment: Actually, your count example will return the number of values in the last 300 seconds equal to 0. You then compare it to 5. The overall effect is to trigger an event if 5 or more "0" values occurred in the last 300 seconds.